# IONIC 4 gradle failed

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7

I'm using IONIC 5.2.4.
when run command ionic cordova build android throw this exception
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>          - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom
>          - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.jar
>          - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom
>          - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.jar
>        Required by:

any one help me :-(

Comment: What commands are you running ?

Comment: Ionic cordova build android